# How using POJO helps Spring

Tags: spring, pojo

I am going through Spring document and confused about how using POJO helps Spring.

In this tutorial - https://data-flair.training/blogs/advantages-of-spring/ , it says

> It uses POJO’s which is an abbreviation for Plain Old Java Object. 
>       Using POJO for developing an application is that you don’t need an enterprise container like an application server. 
>       Also, it helps you get rid of conventional Enterprise Java Beans (EJB) by letting you can use a robust servlet container like Tomcat. This makes Spring Framework a lightweight framework.

I know in Spring we can initialize a POJO very conveniently by annotating the class as @Component. I just don't get what it means by saying

> you don’t need an enterprise container like an application server.

To me, application sever is not just container. Does this mean Spring don't need application server?

As to

> Also, it helps you get rid of conventional Enterprise Java Beans (EJB) by letting you can use a robust servlet container like Tomcat.

Tomcat is web server and naturally we cannot use EJB with Tomcat. I don't see why this is an advantage of Spring.

Answer (score 1):

Using POJO standards is a convenience for spring, so that it can rely on a uniform way to inject things. It simplifies the code if it can assume that setters follow expected conventions. Spring wanted a convention that everybody was already familiar with, and JavaBeans came in handy for that.

An application server is a platform for hosting applications, it provides access to resources like databases and queues and lets you coordinate changes across these resources using XA transactions. It is called a "container" because it provides an environment where applications live.

If you wanted to build Java applications with EJB you had no alternative to using an application server, even if you didn't need XA transactions. You couldn't use Tomcat with EJB, you had to have an application server.

So all it is saying is that Spring is flexible and can work with an application server like JBoss or WebSphere, or it can work with a servlet container like Tomcat, and there isn't a requirement that you use an application server if you don't otherwise want it.